# Solidus (Ruby on Rails) - how to change the logo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solidus

I have the demo app up and running but I changed the `config/initializers/spree.rb` to show:

```
#Frontend:

#Custom logo for the frontend
config.logo = "logo/1.png"
```

to change the place it looks for the logo at ,BUT (huge butt)
im getting an image error. it displays the name of the picture but not the image.

**I Have Already Tired installing ImageMagick**

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install imagemagick --fix-missing
```

Yet, still no image

Answer (score 5):

### Change the logo image in Solidus

Within your Solidus application

1. Copy the new logo into the logo directory `app/assets/images/logo/1.png`
2. Change the image name that the solidus application expects in the configuration file `config/initializers/spree.rb` you can the [find the Solidus template code here](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/blob/v2.1/core/lib/generators/spree/install/templates/config/initializers/spree.rb).

   ```
   Spree.config do |config|
     # Frontend:

     # Custom logo for the frontend
     # config.logo = "logo/solidus_logo.png"
     config.logo = "logo/1.png"
   end
   ```
3. Restart the Rails server to reload the initialization code and refresh the browser page.

#### Further Reading

- [Spree Documentation](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/asset.html) - Solidus was based on Spree and they recommend overriding the images.
- [Advanced video on overriding the logo code - for adding css classes to the image](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFalBLRMgdI&t=11m15s).

Comment: This answer is almost correct - Just put the new logo in app/assets/images/logo/1.png - remember the images before the logo. Otherwise, good to go.

Answer (score 0):

put you image inside app/assest/images and write below code in your view file.

```
 <%= image_tag '1.png' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually that happens in Rails when the image can't be found.  The image tag will be created with the `alt` attribute set and that will be displayed when the image can't be loaded.

Keep in mind that the config value is referencing images in `app/assets/images`.  So in your case the image should be in `app/assets/images/logo/1.png`.

Hope that helps!